# Calculate integral of  $ \int\sin^2(mx) \,dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate   $ \displaystyle\int\sin^2(mx) \,dx$. My steps are the following. Please tell me if I am wrong  in it.

So  if we substitute  $u=m x$  then $du=m \,dx$, so 
 $$\frac {1} {m}\int \sin^2 u du$$ then  we kow that,  $ \sin ^2u=\dfrac{1-\cos(2u)}{2}$ and if we put   this into original integral and evaluate it,we get $$\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{\sin(2mx)}{4m}+ C$$

Am I correct? Or there is some mistake? Please give me any hint  if necessary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, as long as $m\neq 0$.

You could have checked your answer though by simply differentiating w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: @fretty: Very good point about checking.